# Bundle Identifier submitting app to appstore

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

Thsi is extremely frustrating....whhen trying to validate, I am told my bundle ID doesn't match the one on iTunes connect.

On iTunes connect:

`Bundle ID:My App-*` (just like that, with a space and -* at the end)

```
Bundle Suffix:ABC
```

Currently, in Xcode, the following is filled in for Bundle Identifier:
`ABC.My-App` (My-App) is grayed out and I cannot change it.

Please help me, I don't know why the submission process is so tedious.

Comment: Bundle identifiers are a critical component of your app, both for the system, and for you as a developer.  Change the BID in iTunes Connect (which involves a resubmission), because I do not recommend you change the name of your product to *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is your answer. Your bundle ID in iTunesConnect and the bundle ID in Xcode should be identical. In your provisioning portal, create an App ID with the exact sami bundle ID of your project. The one with the `*` symbol was working, because it was a `wildcard` ID, but you should create a new one when you want to submit to the App Store.